# click underlying external player through div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to press a button of an external radioplayer that i have on my website and at the same time register that click to indicate that the user is listening to the radiostation.
The embedded player comes from http://rad.io .

What seemed to get closen was the following in css for the overlaying div:

```
pointer-events:none;
background-image:url(../img/transparent.png);
```

Which indeed enables me to click through but unable to register the click on the overlaying div.

The css:

```
#radio{
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
left: 100px;
height: 30px;
width: 300px;
}

#overlay{
position: absolute;
pointer-events:none;
top: 0px;
right: 30px;
width: 40px;
height: 30px;   
background-image:url(../img/transparent.png);
z-index:2;
opacity: 0.1;

}
```

The html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="chooseradio"><input type="button" id="choose" value="Select        station" onclick= "selectradio();"/></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="radio">'.$userlistening.'</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e){
    $('#radio').click();
}
```

Import jquery, then either put this in script tags or in your js file if you have one.

Comment: I do not want to click the underlying div but a button of a player that is within that div. It should start the player but also register the click on the overlaying div.